# Use IdentityServer4 to allow Employee Login via ADFS using SAML2 and then issue a JWT

Tags: identityserver4, saml-2.0, adfs4.0

My goal is to provide an internet facing application that can be used by both corporate employees and external users. I would have 2 ADFS instances behind an IdentityServer4 instance, one for external users and one for corporate employees.

In general all users(employees or external) should always get an oAuth2 Token to call internet facing APIs, but when there are internal calls between SAML dependent corporate systems, the internal calls should be able to get a SAML2 token or impersonate a corporate corporate user.

No problem with external users, using openid and oAuth2. The main focus is employee login via SAML2.

The setup is as below:

1. IdentityServer4 sits in the front backed by ADFS
2. Client applications should connect with IdentityServer4 using OpenId specs (/connect/authorize? end point. I know how to do that
3. IdentityServer4 should connect to ADFS for external users setup via Ws-Fed. I know how to get till here.
4. IdentityServer4 should connect to internal ADFS for corporate employees over SAML2. It would be nice to be able to switch between the two ADFS' instances based on user's email address. Just like on Azure you get a message: we are taking you to  your employer's login page, if user entered a known corporate email domain. This switch should happen via IdentityServer UI though, probably mimicking Home Realm Discovery feature.
5. IdentityServer4 should issue oAuth tokens in either case.
   6 When connecting to corporate ADFS via SAML2, IdentityServer4 should receive a signed, encrypted SAML2 token response and it should then issue regular oAuth token for external APIs
6. Some external APIs might want to call internal corporate SAML based APIs, (*only for corporate users) There must be a way to impersonate the user, get his SAML token and pass to corporate APIs.

If all of that makes sense, 
 - how can I achieve step 5,6 and 7? 
 - Is there a middleware that can exchange SAML2 token with ADFS? 
 - Is it just possible to pass this SAML2 token directly to internal SAML
   supporting systems?

I have never used SAML2 token before so I am a little lost as to how does it look like, is it something like an access token or is it something to be built using the assertions in ADFS response?

I know I asked a lot of questions but everything is related. I am exploring SustainSys but haven't been able to find way to plug it in to do what I want to do.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a regular federation where the IdP plays a role of so called *relying STS* (R-STS). The fact that you switch protocols on the R-STS is just a technical detail. Anyway, this is doable with custom code, we do such things daily with our custom identity providers. Unfortunately, I have never used the IS4 so I can't help in this specific setup. I don't believe there exists a middleware that does what you want, rather, you'd have to write one by yourself, knowing how both protocols (SAML2 and OAuth2) work internally.